# Does Java create a new instance of iterator() each time it's called?

Tags: java, iterator

I have the following code in a class :

```
private HashMap<Long, Item> items;
private Iterator<Item> iterator;

@Override
public Iterator<Item> iterator()
{
    iterator = items.values().iterator();
    return iterator;
}
```

I would like to know if this would cause a new instance of iterator to be returned each time, i.e. If getting two iterators from this method would return references to the same object.

Also, are there any other visible discrepancies in this code?

Comment: What do you mean with "visible discrepancies"?

Comment: If the program has more than one thread, it is theoretically possible for this to return the same iterator between separate invocations. As the accepted answer points out, it would be bad.

Comment: The only collections I know of that always return the exact same instance when `iterator()` is called are those returned by `Collections.empty...()`. This isn't relevant in your case as `items` is a `HashMap`, but if it had been a plain `Map` this corner case could have applied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each time you call `iterator()` on a standard collection, a new Iterator is created. Otherwise it would be impossible to have multiple iterators which point to different elements of the same collection.

You assign the iterator you get to a member-variable, so every time your `iterator()` method is called, the `private Iterator<Item> iterator` will be reset. I am unsure why you would create and return an iterator and also store that iterator in a private variable, but you surely got your reasons...