# Why do I get different results when calling the iterator with different methods?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    set.add(i);
}

Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}

System.out.println("================================");

while (set.iterator().hasNext()){
    System.out.println(set.iterator().next());
}
```

[you're supposed to actually enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJwAq.png)

I want to traverse the set collection, so I use the Iterator to create an iterator object and use the collection to call iterator directly, but the former gives the correct result, while the latter is an infinite loop.
I don't understand it and could you tell me the difference between these two? thank you!

Comment: yep. According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27728424/16034206), everytime you call set.iterator() you get a new iterator that starts at the beginning, and you call .next on it so you get the first item, then you reset the iterator again

Comment: The sentence “I use the Iterator to create an iterator object” makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Iterators are *stateful* and maintain their own state. Simplified: they remember their current position in the collection.

Calling `.iterator()` on a collection (actually a `java.lang.Iterable<T>`) gives you a *NEW* iterator instance every time. So `while (set.iterator.hasNext())` will always create a new iterator which starts at the beginning. The only way this loop can exit is by having an empty set (in that case, the loop will never be entered).

By calling `.iterator()` only once and storing the instance in a variable, you can advance this iterator (and update its internal state/position).